# Python Beep Noise on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to create a little timer program that will have the user's computer beep when the timer is finished.

Being on a Mac, the `winsound` library is not available, and I cannot get `\a` to generate any noise at all.

How would I go about generating a little ding or beep or some other sound when the timer is finished?

Comment: what python are you using? are you running it on the terminal or somwehere else?

Comment: Are you trying `\a` from inside Python? Remember that `\a` can also be used from the Terminal in Mac by using `printf "\a"` at the prompt. So, if I were you, I would try
` >>> import os >>> os.system("printf \"a\"")`
This should print a 0 and generate a beep sound, assuming your speaker and sound drivers are working fine, and your Mac is not muted.

Comment: If you want to be more fancy, just execute `afplay <path to sound file>`. This is of course os specific to os x.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

works for me

Comment: @Zizouz212 I did this on a mac, and had succes because of the call to sys.stdout.flush(). That's what I was trying to portray. Did you make any effort to see what was different about my response?